# applet verification of XADES (xml) signatures

Tags: java, applet, digital-signature, xml-signature

I would like to create an applet (java) in order to verify detached XADES signature associated with the original file.
I 'm using an open source program from "svn://scm.adullact.net/scmrepos/svn/libersign/trunk". I configure it correctly but unfortunately I get a run time exception on this line

```
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature xmlSignature = signatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(validateContext);
 xmlSignature.validate(validateContext);
```

here is the exception :

```
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: It is forbidden to access resolver com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverLocalFilesystem when secure validation is enabled
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.adullact.XADESVerUtil.verify(XADESVerUtil.java:140)
    at org.adullact.XADESVerUtil.verify(XADESVerUtil.java:169)
    at org.adullact.VerificationApplet$1.actionPerformed(VerificationApplet.java:163)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: It is forbidden to access resolver com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverLocalFilesystem when secure validation is enabled
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(Unknown Source)
    at org.adullact.ContextSpecificURIDereferencer.dereference(ContextSpecificURIDereferencer.java:32)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: It is forbidden to access resolver com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverLocalFilesystem when secure validation is enabled
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: It is forbidden to access resolver com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverLocalFilesystem when secure validation is enabled
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(Unknown Source)
    at org.adullact.ContextSpecificURIDereferencer.dereference(ContextSpecificURIDereferencer.java:32)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.adullact.XADESVerUtil.verify(XADESVerUtil.java:140)
    at org.adullact.XADESVerUtil.verify(XADESVerUtil.java:169)
    at org.adullact.VerificationApplet$1.actionPerformed(VerificationApplet.java:163)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: It is forbidden to access resolver com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverLocalFilesystem when secure validation is enabled
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

I'm using jdk1.7.0_71

Can any one help me please,

Comment: Could you please create a question that includes the source. It's against SO rules to require us to download source code from another site. The site may be removed, to name one reason.

Comment: Thanks for your response :), I contact the creator of this application, and he said that'is not work with XADES. did you know another open source code which is used to validate XADES signature ? thanks in advance